# Filter Rank Based On Column Not being Ordered By

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Here is some fake/sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (PersonID VARCHAR(255), FirstNM VARCHAR(100), FileNBR VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl1 (PersonID, FirstNM, FileNBR) VALUES
('456789', 'NONAME', 'FileNBR780'),
('456789', 'John', 'FileNBR781'),
('456789', 'NONAME', 'FileNBR783'),
('476362', 'NONAME', 'FileNBR780'),
('476362', 'Mary', 'FileNBR781'),
('476362', 'Mary', 'FileNBR783')
```

```
PersonID  FirstNM   FileNBR
456789    NONAME    FileNBR780
456789    John      FileNBR781
456789    NONAME    FileNBR783
476362    NONAME    FileNBR780
476362    Mary      FileNBR781
476362    Mary      FileNBR783
```

I am trying to rank off of FileNBR and PersonID. I'd like to make any PersonID that has a FirstNM of "NONAME" to be the last ranked, despite the ranking in the FileNM.

Here is what I have so far.  How do you achieve NONAME not being ranked first?

```
SELECT
 PersonID
 ,FirstNM  
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY FileNBR ASC) AS RankNBR
FROM @tbl1
```

Which yields these results:

```
PersonID    FirstNM  RankNBR
456789      NONAME   1
456789      John     2
456789      NONAME   3
476362      NONAME   1
476362      Mary     2
476362      Mary     3
```

But, these are the desired Results:

```
PersonID    FirstNM  RankNBR
456789      John     1
456789      NONAME   2
456789      NONAME   3
476362      Mary     1
476362      Mary     2
476362      NONAME   3
```

Comment: It's MySQL _or_ SSMS. Which one are you using?

Comment: @jarlh, it is in SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need another ordering condition to rank your nonames before the `RankNBR`

```
SELECT
 PersonID
 ,FirstNM  
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY case when firstNM='NONAME' then 1 else 0 end,FileNBR ASC) AS RankNBR
FROM @tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select
  PersonID,
  FirstNM,
  row_number() over(
    partition by PersonId 
    order by
      case when FirstNm = 'NONAME' then 'ZZZZ' else FirstNM end
  ) as RankNBR
from @tbl1
```

It's not clear in your definition if you are ordering by `FirstNM` or `FileNBR`, but to get your desired output you must do something like that.